# Extracting the immediate parent directory from a file path using boost

Tags: c++, boost, std, boost-filesystem

Assuming I have

```
String t = "c:/foo/foo1/foo2/foo3/file.txt"
```

I want to extract `"foo3/file.txt"`.

How can I do this (using boost or std)?

Here is what I've been trying to so far:

```
boost::filesystem::path pathToObject(t);
```

Using `pathToObject.filename()` I can extract the file name of course. And I've played around with `t.find_last_of("/")` but I really need like `t.find_second_to_last_of("/")`.

Comment: What have you tried? Why haven't you taken the [Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)?

Comment: Thanks for your answers and to my @joshj777.  Here is the solution I ended up using:

        std::string t = pathObject.parent_path().filename().string();
   t.append("/");
   t.append(pathObject.filename().string());

Comment: You should accept one of the answers below. (It can be your own, but it does not have to.)

Comment: Thanks! Hermann! Long time lurker and user. Looking to participating more.

Comment: A solved problem without an accepted answer triggers my [not-an-actual-OCD](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tnzz-eFmKaw). So, could you fix that for me?

Answer (score 2):

`string::find_last_of` has an [optional argument](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find_last_of/) which lets you specify how far into the string you are looking.

So you can define

```
size_t second_to_last = t.find_last_of("/", t.find_last_of("/")-1);
std::string file_with_parent = t.substr(second_to_last+1);
```

The second argument tells him to only search *before* the last `/`.

**WARNING:** This might differ from what you want if you have stuff like `"C:/bli/bla//blubb.txt"`. In general, paths can be complex and confusing and trying to conquer them with string manipulation will only work for very well-behaved input, which one usually can't assume.

I therefore recommended using a proper tool for this job.* But since the question claimed that `find_last_of` wouldn't do the job I felt quite compelled to remind people that the standard facilities are not entirely as impotent as many seem to believe them to be.

*I suspect the boost path lib to be one but I have never worked with it.

Comment: I like the simplicity. People tend to forget about standard library utilities. However, I wouldn't personally go here if I wanted path manipulation, because paths aren't so predictable in real life. +1 nonetheless

Comment: @sehe Whelp, since the note about this not working reliably apparently did not come across, I expanded it to a bold warning. Happy now? (=

Comment: Oh. I was happy before. I don't see many downvotes either, so you don't have to worry that much.

Comment: Better safe than sorry. If someone dies because some idiot blindly copied my code, I want to be able to say “but I *warned* them”. That's nearly as good as noone dying in the first place!

Comment: Also, I don't get to what you refer to with the “[not] many downvotes”.

Answer (score 1):

It is rather odd to extract a path like that. Maybe you are looking for a relative path? boost filesystem has a tool for that. Be sure to give the [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html) a good look over. But to answer your question:

```
namespace bfs= boost::filesystem;
    int main( ) {
        bfs::path path( "c:/foo/foo1/foo2/foo3/file.txt" );
        bfs::path target( path );
        target.remove_filename( );
        target= target.filename( ) / path.filename( );
        std::cout << target << std::endl;
    }
```

Comment: Yea what I'm essentially doing is looking for just the parent directory of the file.

Comment: Then remove `filename` and the `filename` of what is left is your parent directory. That is in the code I posted.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a compiler handy to test it, but based on the example here, this code should basically work or point you in about the right direction. It could probably be simplified a little bit even from what I've written here.

```
path p1( "c:/foo/foo1/foo2/foo3/file.txt" );
path p2;
for (path::iterator it(p1.end()), int i = 0; it != p1.begin() && i < 2; --it, ++i) {
  path temp = p2;
  p2 = it;
  p2 /= temp;
}
```

Comment: This is ridiculously complicated. Definitely bad advice, but it *does have* a strange beauty. (=

Comment: The "strange beauty" is because it's considerably more generic than most other solutions are likely to be. This solution can be abstracted to n levels of the path rather than 2 with only a few more lines of code.

Comment: So can mine. Just loop to `n`, always remembering the position of the `i`th last slash. To me, the beauty is in using *two* iterators where I don't think a single one should be used.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution I ended up using:

```
std::string t = pathObject.parent_path().filename().string();
t.append("/");
t.append(pathObject.filename().string());
```

Using `parent_path` gave me just the path. Then I used the `filename` to extract just the directory.  Then I appended the `filename` of the child directory.

Comment: If it were me. I would keep path objects as boost paths. There is no need to go from string to path to string. I've added an important line to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Following method return immediate parent directory.

```
#include <string>
string getParentDirectory(string& filePath)
{
    if (filePath.empty() == false)
    {
        size_t toPos = filePath.find_last_of('\\') - 1;
        if (toPos != string::npos)
        {
            size_t fromPos = filePath.find_last_of('\\', toPos);
            if (fromPos != string::npos)
            {
                return filePath.substr(fromPos + 1, toPos - fromPos);
            }
        }
    }

    return "";
}

int main() 
{
    string str = "D:\\Devs\\Test\\sprite.png";

    string parentDir = getParentDirectory(str);
    return 0;
}
```

It prints the value of parentDir is "Test".